# VirtualBox, Ubuntu clients, internal network proxy to supply internet

Tags: virtualbox, proxy, iptables

Probably this question was asked many times, but I seem to be unable to find proper solution.

Here is my setup:

- Two virtual machines(Ubuntu 12.04) *M1* and *M2*.
- *M1* has 2 network adapters: `eth0` set to `NAT` and `eth1` set as `Internal Network` in VirtualBox.
- *M2* has 1 network adapter, setup as `Internal Network` in VirtualBox.

I want to setup *M1* as proxy(using `iptables`), so that *M2* has Internet access.

Here are some more details:

### M1 Configuration:

**iptables rules:**

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080 
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth1 -s 192.168.10.150 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

**Interfaces configuration:**

```
auto eth0    
iface eth0 inet dhcp    

auto eth1    
iface eth1 inet static    
address 192.168.10.125    
netmask 255.255.255.0    
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

### M2 Configuration:

**Interfaces configuration:**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.10.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

**Kernel IP routing table:**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.125     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```